# Can I turn this into a lambda statement?

Tags: c#, lambda, while-loop

I was wondering if it's possible to turn this while loop into a lambda statement? I know it's possible if it were a for or a foreach loop, but it's a normal, plain while loop:

```
while (path.Substring(path.Length - 4) != ".txt" || path.Substring(path.Length - 4) != ".xml")
{
    Console.WriteLine("File not a .txt or .xml extension! Enter the file name:");
    path = Console.ReadLine();
}
```

If it is possible, how would one transform this loop into such a lambda statement?

Comment: Why would you want to do that?

Comment: And, why is this a while loop to begin with? It looks like a very simple if statement.

Comment: You can turn any statement into a lambda: `new Action(() => { while (...) { ... } })();`. This is completely useless, but you don't seem to be asking for something that *is* useful. Can you elaborate?

Comment: @ChrisDixon No, that part makes sense. As long as the user keeps on entering invalid file names, the program prompts for a valid file name.

Comment: Have a look at `Path.GetExtension(string path)`

Comment: I'm working on a school project and I'm trying to minimize my code. Part of the project needs to check if the file is a .xml or a .txt

Comment: Fair enough @hvd, didn't think of that :)

Comment: @Kennedy, then your code is already fine. You do not need lambdas here.

Comment: And what happens when `path` is very short, like `"x"`? You need to check for that.

Answer (score 2):

Given that the comments on the question suggest that this isn't really about lambdas, but about minimizing code, here are some small suggestions to avoid some code duplication:

```
string[] validExtensions = { ".txt", ".xml" };
do
{
    Console.WriteLine("Enter the file name:");
    path = Console.ReadLine();
    if (!validExtensions.Contains(Path.GetExtension(path)))
    {
        Console.Write("File not a .txt or .xml extension! ");
        path = null;
    }
}
while (path == null);
```

Checking for another extension merely requires adding the extension to the array, it doesn't require duplicating the code to determine the extension. The string `"Enter the file name:"` only has to appear once, even if you want a slightly different message for the first prompt. The code to read a line also only has to appear once.

Personally, I'd say the duplication you had is so small that there is no need to avoid it yet, but you may find this useful if, for example, you need to allow three more extensions, or read from some other location where a single function call does not suffice.

Some additional comments:

- `Console.ReadLine()` can return `null`. Just like the code in your question, this version doesn't handle that properly.
- Case in file extensions is usually ignored. Do you really want to reject `".TXT"` as a file extension?
- Your `while` condition `path.Substring(path.Length - 4) != ".txt" || path.Substring(path.Length - 4) != ".xml"` would never be false. It could be true, or it could throw an exception, but the loop would never terminate normally.

Answer (score 0):

In case you want to do this for learning and academic purposes:

```
Func<string[], string> getFile = (validExtensions) =>
    {
        string path = "";
        while (!validExtensions.Contains(Path.GetExtension(path)))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("File not a .txt or .xml extension! Enter the file name:");
            path = Console.ReadLine();
        }
        return path;
    };

   string path = getFile.Invoke(new string[]{ ".txt", ".xml" });
```

Use `.Invoke(string[])` to call it, passing in desired file extensions.

To pass it into a method, for example:

```
public string UseFunc(Func<string[], string> getFile, string[] validExtensions)
{
    return getFile.Invoke(validExtensions);
}

string path = foo.UseFunc(getFile);
```

Comment: This won't compile. And even if you change it to something that does compile, it'll be useless, which is why I put something similar as a comment on the question, rather than an answer.

Comment: How will you do anything with the path the user enters, if you keep it in a variable local to the anonymous method?

Comment: I don't know, return it?